# How can I save every Outlook Express Email as an html without clicking "Save As" for every email

Tags: javascript, python, html, email, outlook

I am trying to save a whole slew of emails as html in Outlook Express, but the program only lets me save them individually. If I click "Save As" on more than one email Outlook only lets me save them all in one `.txt` file. I was able to drag all of the files into a folder outside of outlook, but their file type is `Outlook Item`. Thus, I am trying to find a way to save all of these files in `html`. I have looked at a number of programs, such as `SAFE PST Backup`, but they didn't seem to have this functionality.

If there were a way to do this in either Python or JavaScript that would be awesome, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: This is a programming question about how to iterate over a lot of Outlook Express Items and save them to html.

Comment: Then you should mention a programming language, and not talk about the various apps you've tried using.

Comment: So I ended up just using a tool called Total Outlook Converter (http://www.coolutils.com/totaloutlookconverter), which isn't really ideal but at least you can select multiple (hundreds) of files to convert at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook Express, unlike real Outlook, does not provide any API to enumerate its messages. The only API exposed by OE is Simple MAPI.